# R - How can I use the apply functions instead of iterating?

Tags: r, linear-regression

### Regress each dependent variable ( dep_var ) against independent variable ( ind_var )

I am trying to perform linear regressions for multiple dependent variables against a independent variable ***one at a time.***

When there is a missing observation (*NA*) , the entire row is not used for that particular regression.

I have done it by looping/iterating through each column of dependent variable.

```
fit = list()
for( i in 1 : 2 ) {
    fit[[i]] = lm( mydf$Ind_Var[ which( !is.na( mydf[  , (2+i) ] ) ) ] ~ na.omit( mydf[ , (2+i) ] ) )
    }
```

Without having to involve other packages ( let's restrict to functions like *lm*, *apply family functions* , *do/do.call*), how can I do so?

#### Random Data

```
mydf = data.frame( 
"ID"    = rep( "A" , 25 ),
"Date"  = c( 1 : 25 ), 
"Dep_1" = c( 0.78670185, 0.15221561, NA, 0.85270392, 0.90057399, 0.75974473, 0.42026760, 0.64035871, 0.83012434, 0.04985492, 0.06619375, 0.36024745, 0.83969627, 0.45293842, 0.25272036, NA, 0.63783321, 0.42294695, 0.06726004, 0.14124547, 0.54590193, 0.99560087, 0.14255501, 0.41559977, 0.80120970) ,          
"Dep_2" = c( 0.736137983, 0.979317444, 0.901380500, 0.942325049, 0.420741297, NA, 0.243408607, 0.824064331, 0.462912557, NA, 0.710834065, 0.264922818, 0.797917063, 0.578866651, 0.955944058, 0.291149075, 0.437322581, 0.298153168, 0.579299049, 0.671718144, 0.545720702, 0.099175216, 0.808933227, 0.912825535, 0.417438973 ) ,          
"Ind_Var" = c( 75:51 )  )
```

---

My own attempt of converting will be:

```
apply( mydf[ ,-c(1:2) ] , 2 , function( x ) lm( mydf$Ind_Var[ which( !is.na( x ) ) ] ~ na.omit(x)  ) )
```

but this involves having *mydf* hardcoded.

I apologize if I have used any incorrect terms.

Comment: `foreach` doesn't look like a base function.

Comment: I only used `foreach` to create the list, but I have edited it to `for` now for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following approach

```
# Specify the columns that contain your predictor variables
predIdx <- c(3, 4);

# lm(y ~ x), for x being a single predictor
lapply(predIdx, function(x) lm(mydf[, ncol(mydf)] ~ mydf[, x]))
```

Here I assume that the response is always in the last column of the dataframe. All you need to specify manually are the column indices that contain your predictors.

If you want to manually exclude the NAs you could use `complete.cases` inside the `lapply` function; this shouldn't be necessary because `lm` (by default) deals with NA's.

---

I'm not sure what you mean by "having mydf hardcoded". You can wrap above code inside a function to make it more general, for any dataframe `df`, with predictors given in columns `predIdx` and the independent variable given in column `respIndx`.

```
one_at_a_time_LM <- function(df, predIdx, respIdx) {
    lapply(predIdx, function(x) lm(df[, respIdx] ~ df[, x]))
}

one_at_a_time_LM(mydf, c(3, 4), 5);
```

Comment: In the code I used, I had `lm( mydf$Ind_Var ....)` . I wanted it to be more general like just `x`.

I guess a better way to say it would have been to say manually specify, as you did.

It is quite vague, but hopefully this made sense.

Comment: I see. In that case, creating a general function like `one_at_a_time_LM` would be the way to go...