# Many individual dependent variables, code for one by one linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have two datasets "bear" and "frog" and I am trying to write a function, which would take 
columns one by one from "bear" as dependent variable in linear regression with same regressors in 
all cases, print the name of the column in each case and the summary of linear regression with 
coefficients, standard errors, t-value, R squared and residual standard errors.I want to get 25 separate outputs

I tried the following code

```
  print(lm(bear[,i]~frog$MK_RF+frog$SMB+frog$HML))
  print(colnames(bear[,i])) 
  summary (lm(bear[,i]~frog$Mkt.RF+frog$SMB+frog$HML))}
```

I wrote this function, but instead of column name i get NULL, and the summary only shows coefficients, no error message.
For reproductible examples:

```
# dput(head(frog, 10))
frog <- structure(list(date = c(192607L, 192608L, 192609L, 192610L, 192611L, 
192612L, 192701L, 192702L, 192703L, 192704L), Mkt.RF = c(2.96, 
2.64, 0.36, -3.24, 2.53, 2.62, -0.06, 4.18, 0.13, 0.46), SMB = c(-2.3, 
-1.4, -1.32, 0.04, -0.2, -0.04, -0.56, -0.1, -1.6, 0.43), HML = c(-2.87, 
4.19, 0.01, 0.51, -0.35, -0.02, 4.83, 3.17, -2.67, 0.6), RF = c(0.22, 
0.25, 0.23, 0.32, 0.31, 0.28, 0.25, 0.26, 0.3, 0.25)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

and for the bear dataset

```
# dput(head(bear[, 1:3], 10)) 
bear <- structure(list(date = c(192607L, 192608L, 192609L, 192610L, 192611L, 
192612L, 192701L, 192702L, 192703L, 192704L), SMALL.LoBM = c(3.5582, 
-2.4574, -6.4413, -8.9441, 3.1644, 13.6658, 0.1974, 2.2284, 6.0998, 
5.5863), ME1.BM2 = c(-0.6319, -8.9775, -0.5289, -4.0732, 6.3376, 
-2.2572, -8.5499, -0.5649, -2.0464, 7.5611)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this has got to be a duplicate ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822631/r-how-can-i-use-the-apply-functions-instead-of-iterating ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060985/function-which-runs-lm-over-different-variables; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907726/running-multiple-linear-regressions-across-several-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719732/r-automated-loop-of-linear-regressions-using-same-ivs-on-different-dvs-to-store ...

Comment: Can't you just do `lm(bear ~ frog$MK_RF+frog$SMB+frog$HML)`? I.e multivariate multiple regression. https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-multivariate-multiple-regression/

Comment: No, i get error message "invalid type (list) for variable bear"

Comment: @Maria: Try converting it to matrix `lm(as.matrix(bear) ~ frog$MK_RF+frog$SMB+frog$HML)`

Comment: @AkselA error message again "Error in model.frame.default(formula = as.matrix(bear) ~ frog$MK_RF +  : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'frog$MK_RF'".

Comment: `dput(head(frog, 10))
structure(list(date = c(192607L, 192608L, 192609L, 192610L, 192611L, 
192612L, 192701L, 192702L, 192703L, 192704L), Mkt.RF = c(2.96, 
2.64, 0.36, -3.24, 2.53, 2.62, -0.06, 4.18, 0.13, 0.46), SMB = c(-2.3, 
-1.4, -1.32, 0.04, -0.2, -0.04, -0.56, -0.1, -1.6, 0.43), HML = c(-2.87, 
4.19, 0.01, 0.51, -0.35, -0.02, 4.83, 3.17, -2.67, 0.6), RF = c(0.22, 
0.25, 0.23, 0.32, 0.31, 0.28, 0.25, 0.26, 0.3, 0.25)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")` and for `dput(head(bear, 10))` the output is too long to be posted, it has 2575 characters..

Comment: Good. Now we can both work with the same data. You may delete the unneeded comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because you used the wrong name for one of the variables (there is no `frog$MK_RF`). The correct call would be

```
lm(as.matrix(bear) ~ frog$Mkt.RF+frog$SMB+frog$HML)
```

or

```
mmod <- lm(as.matrix(bear) ~ Mkt.RF + SMB + HML, data=frog)
summary(mmod)
```

This gives precisely the same coefficients, standard errors, t-values etc. as if you had looped over the columns in `bear` individually. Doing it this way has multiple advantages, however.

Try, f.ex.

```
anova(mmod)
coef(mmod)
residuals(mmod)
```

Very handy.

Comment: Or maybe even `lm(as.matrix(bear) ~ . - date , data=frog)`

Comment: Yes, if all the columns are being used and no fancy interactions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend that you merge your data frames: relying on the row ordering being consistent is dangerous. The only reason not to is if your data sets are enormous and you can't afford the extra memory consumption.

```
bear_vars <- names(bear)[-1]
frog_vars <- names(frog)[-1]
bf <- merge(bear, frog, by = "date")
```

Now loop, using `reformulate()` to build a linear model formula with the values in `frog_vars` as the predictor (independent) variables and each value in `bear_vars` as the response (dependent) variable:

```
for (b in bear_vars) {
    m <- lm(reformulate(frog_vars, response=b), data=bf)
    cat(b,"\n")
    print(m)
    print(summary(m))
}
```

You can use tidyverse methods if you want, but this should work OK.